# How to write custom event which gets fired when user click three times

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to write a custom event which should get fire when user click three times on any html node.

i know that i can create even using

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
evt.initEvent("myEvent",true,true);
```

but i am not getting how i will capture that three times click event.

I will be appreciated if some one can suggest me the write approach for this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is it three times over *any* period of time, or three quick clicks (like a `dblclick`)?

Comment: yes.. it's `three quick clicks` like `dblclick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a special event
[Code and example](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/#setup-and-teardown-tripleclick) - here is your problem solvation :)

Answer (score 2):

Just create a variable that stores the number of clicks.

```
var clickTimes = 0;

element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    clickTimes++;
    if(clickTimes==3) { 
        clickTimes = 0;
        /* do something like dispatch my custom event */ 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will count the clicks for any specific element and trigger Event on every third click.

```
$('selector').on('click',function(e){
    Event_threshold = 500;

    var clicked_times = $(this).data('Event-clicked-times');

    if(clicked_times == '')
        clicked_times = 0;

    if(clicked_times == 0)
        $(this).data('Event-first-click-timestamp',e.timeStamp);

    clicked_times++;

    if(e.timeStamp-$(this).data('Event-first-click-timestamp')<Event_threshold)
    {
        if(clicked_times == 3)
        {
            $(this).data('Event-clicked-times',0);
            $(this).trigger('Event');
        }
        else
            $(this).data('Event-clicked-times',clicked_times);

    }
    else
         $(this).data('Event-clicked-times',0);
});
```

EDIT:
Fixed and added threshold control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create iteration variable and check if element was three times clicked.

For example:

```
var clickTimer = 0;
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clickTimer++;
    if(clickTimer == 3) {
        clickTimer = 0;
        // fire your event
    }
}, true);
```

To make this behavior like `dbclick` you can compare timestamp with first click.

For example:

```
var clickTimes = 0;
var fisrtClickTime = 0;

element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    clickTimes++;
    if(clickTimes == 1) {
        fisrtClickTime = +new Date();
    }
    if(clickTimes == 3) { 
        clickTimes = 0;
        firstClickTime = 0;
        if((+new Date() - fisrtClickTime) < 1000) {
            /* do something like dispatch my custom event */ 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works without using external variables, using the HTML5 "data-" attribute for storage, so you will work on multiple elements.

```
$('#yourLink').click(function() {
     window.setTimeout(function() {$(this).data("count",1)},300)
     if(typeof $(this).data("count")=='undefined') {
         $(this).data("count",1) 
     }
     else {
       var myCount = parseInt($(this).data("count"))
       myCount++      
       if(myCount==3) {
          alert("3!")
          $(this).data("count",0)
       }
        else {
           $(this).data("count",myCount)
        }    
    }

})
```